# PHP <Select> box creation is slow

Tags: php

I have a site with 2 groups of 2 select boxes each containing about 5,000 records, with each group containing the same data, just displayed in a different order with the data being stored in a mysql table.

I am finding the creation/loading speed of these drop down boxes to be be approximately 1-2 seconds per box and I was wondering if there might be any little tricks to help speed things up?

I tried retrieving the data just once, into an array, resorting the array and then creating the second drop down box from that, but that was even slower.

With the exception of the fact that one record in each drop down list 'may' need to be marked as 'selected' the contents of the list is generally static.

With this in mind I tried creating the contents of each list 'once per session' and then doing a str_replace() to mark the necessary record as 'selected' but this took so long over all four boxes to prevent the page from loading at all.

Any suggestions or ideas would be most appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If I'm a user being presented with a select box with 5000 entries, I leave that site and don't come back

Comment: @MarkBaker as long as it's ordered randomly I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Usually people use autocomplete/autosuggest features when handling that amount of records. Selectboxes with 5000 records are slow, hard to look for a certain record and just crazy.

Comment: show us your code, makes it easier to find improvements ;-)

Comment: I recommend you use the HTML5 datalist http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist or try coding something similar for all the browsers ! 5000 is to large like mike said !!

Comment: Well, this section of the site would only be used by the administrators. And yes, thank you, I realise they are slow with this number of records in which is why I am asking for suggestion as to how best to re-present the information :)  Could anyone suggest a good starting place for looking into autocomplete/suggest features...I presume it would need the likes of ajax or such like, of which I am not yet familiar with.

Comment: Thanks Mawran, I will check that one out

Comment: Just done a quick check and that certainly helps no end Marwan...at the bare minimum I can half the number of boxes I need.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of loading is down to several points in your program.

- First, you are pulling 5,000 records out of the database in a given
  order (twice).
- Then you are looping through these items to turn them into HTML
  output.
- Then you are sending all 10,000 items in the page to the browser.
- Lastly, the browser needs to render these items on the page.

You could speed all of this up by reducing the number of items. For example, rather than supply a list of all-towns-in-the-world, supply a text-box the user can enter a town to reduce the size of the list. You could then improve the experience by fetching the smaller matching list of towns for them to select from (and even implement that as an AJAX request so they don't need to submit the page to get the list).

Comment: Thanks Steve....That was my thoughts over this...although I did not put it as clearly as you did.....I need to get into ajax anyway so this looks like the ideal opportunity for me to do so.